# How to switch from solo mining to pool mining?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

I just created my own node for the first time and opted for solo mining.  I changed my mind and want to join a pool.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To mine in a pool, use a dedicated mining app e.g. [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig).